# How does git update local interim (missing on remote) commits on remote branch

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-remote

Say, I have a branch `featureA (A->B->C->F->G)` that has branched off from `master (A->B->C->D->E)` since the 3rd third commit `C`.

When `master` is merged into `featureA`, `featureA` now looks like `featureA (A->B->C->D->E->F->G->T)` where `->D->E` are of `master` and `T` represents the merged commit.

`git status` tells me that `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/featureA' by 3 commits.`

and on pushing `featureA` to *remote's* `featureA`, `featureA` on remote looks like `(A->B->C->D->E->F->G->T)`.

What I'd like to know as to how git merges interim commits `->D->E` (that were initially missing on remote featureA) on remote.

Does git tries to replicate the local `featureA` onto remote `featureA` or internally how it works. I'm not sure if I am correctly phrasing my doubt.

I hope somebody can ascertain my doubt even though it may not be correctly phrased.

thanks
dk

Comment: "When master is merged into featureA, featureA now looks like featureA (A->B->C->D->E->F->G->T)" No it doesnt. Thats a rebase, not a merge

Comment: @tkausl hi, I never used the `rebase` command.

Answer (score 1):

(Side note: [you want the word "question" where you are using "doubt"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2429/180540).)

> ...how [does] git merge interim commits [when pushing]?

The answer is that it *doesn't*.  The `git push` operation simply transfers commits, then sends a "please set" request.  All the real work happens *locally*, in *your own* repository.

If you just want the answer, you can stop here, but if you want to know *why* this is the answer, read on.  You've been misled by the way you drew out what was on each branch.

#### Let's start by drawing commit chains clearly

Let's look at this more closely.  You are on the right track when you draw the commits as a chain, but first, let's adjust the drawing a bit, because Git, internally, works backwards.

> Say, I have a branch featureA (`A->B->C->F->G`) that has branched off from master (`A->B->C->D->E`) since the 3rd third commit `C`.

I like to draw this (here on StackExchange anyway, where graphics are a little difficult) as:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
       \
        F--G   <-- featureA
```

This represents the seven commits using single uppercase letters, rather than Git's actual hash IDs, so we will run out of letters after just 26 commits; but it will serve for our usage here.  Note that the name `master`, in our own repository, simply designates "commit with hash <real hash of`E`>".  Commit `E` itself records the actual hash ID of commit `D`, i.e., `E` *points to* `D`; and commit `D` records the hash ID of `C`, and so on.  The name `featureA` then just records the hash ID of `G`.  So if we wanted to draw the arrows in, we should attach each arrow to the entity that holds it, and make it point backwards (leftwards in this diagram):

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <--master
```

rather than pointing forwards.  This is the first key to understanding all of this: *Git works backwards.*

Another important item, though we won't be using it directly here, is that *all Git objects are read-only once they are stored.*  This explains *why* the arrows *must* be backwards: the hash ID of an object is computed from the object's content.  When we made commit `F`, for instance, we did not yet know what the content of commit `G` would be.  We only knew what the content of `F` was once we made it.  This is because the content of `F` includes the time stamp of *when* `F` is made, along with the snapshot that goes into it, your name and email address (as author and committer), and your log message.  And, to go with that, the hash ID of commit `E` is itself part of commit `F`, so that the hash ID of `F` depends on the hash ID of `E`.

All of this—the hash ID being dependent on all previous hash IDs, and including a time stamp—is part of what guarantees that hash IDs are unique.  (The rest is up to the hash function.)  But it's also why the hashes must necessarily point backwards: a child commit knows who its parents are, because the parents *do* exist when the child is created; but the parents do not know who their children will be when the *parents* are created.

#### The merge operation, minus most of the important details

Let's look now at what `git merge` does in the general case, without getting into *how* it does it (which matters a great deal).  The purpose of a merge, in general, is to combine two different "lines of work".  Often, but not always, these lines of work will have been done by different people or groups.  In Git, though, all the *commits* involved in this merge must be in your own repository by this point, regardless of who actually *made* the commits.  Hence, at this point we must have a diagram much like the one we drew above, but let's repeat it here, after running the command:

```
git checkout featureA
```

You now have this:

```
        F--G   <-- featureA (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

This is the same graph we drew earlier, even though I put `featureA` on top.  A graph has little respect for ordering, and the links—arcs in our case, as this is a *directed* graph—are stretchy.  We can move each graph vertex if needed, to make the drawing work better.  The one important difference is the addition of `(HEAD)` after a branch name.  This is how Git knows which branch we're *on*.  Your `HEAD` in Git is generally attached to some branch; `git checkout branch` prepares your index and work-tree for doing work, and attaches `HEAD` to the given *`branch`*.

Now you run `git merge master`.  (As an aside, it's often wiser to avoid merging *from* master *into* feature branches, but to get there, you will eventually need to learn all about `git rebase`.  Rebasing is considerably more complex once we get into all the details.  This is because rebase works by *copying* commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`, and cherry-pick relies on the merge machinery in Git; so each individual copy is a sort of mini-merge!)

A merge consists of two parts: the *merge action*, or what I like to call *merge as a verb*; followed by making a *merge commit*, which uses the word *merge* as an adjective (modifying commit), or as a noun: *a merge* means *a merge commit* but uses the word *merge* to mean that specific kind of commit.

First, we do the verb, *to merge*, so we execute the merge action.  This consists of finding the *merge base*, which in this case is commit `C`, then somehow combining everything done since `C` on `feature` with everything done since `C` on `master`.  Internally, Git effectively runs two `git diff` commands, comparing `C` vs `G` to find out what *we* did on `--ours` in `HEAD`, and comparing `C` vs `E` to find out what *they* did in `--theirs` on `master`.  It then combines these changes into one big change to be applied to `C` to get the result that we wish to commit.

The last step of `git merge` is to make *a* merge, the merge-as-a-noun.  A merge, or a merge commit, is simply a commit with at least two (and usually exactly two) parent commits.  The two parents are the *current* (`HEAD`) commit as usual, plus the commit you named when you ran `git merge`.  In this case, that's commit `G` as `HEAD`, plus commit `E` because `master` points to `E`.  So we get one new commit, which makes our current branch name, `featureA`, advance as well.  You labeled this commit `T`, so let's put it in as `T` here:

```
        F--G--T   <-- featureA (HEAD)
       /     /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

This is where you made your first mistake:

> When `master` is merged into `featureA`, `featureA` now looks like `featureA (A->B->C->D->E->F->G->T`) where `->D->E` are of master and `T` represents the merged commit.

It's no longer possible to draw the graph *correctly* while also drawing it as a *single line*, because commit `T`, which is the merge, has *two* parents.  One of the two parents—in fact, the first one—is `G`, and the other parent is `E`.  (Git's recording of *first parent* is eventually important, or rather, can be important if you want it to be.  Our more complicated two-dimensional graph drawing does not represent first-vs-second very well, but this is why I put `featureA` on the top row instead of the bottom row.)

#### The `git push` operation

When you run `git push`, you have your Git connect to some other Git.  Both Gits have their own set of branches; both have their own repository of commits (and other Git objects).

We don't really need to know what commits they have except for illustration purposes.  (I could figure some of this out from the `ahead of` message that your Git printed, but I would have to do some guessing.)  Let's assume that what they have looks like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

We run `git push origin featureA:featureA` from *our* end, so our Git, which now has:

```
        F--G--T   <-- featureA (HEAD)
       /     /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

calls up *their* Git.  Our Git could now ask them which commits they have by what names, and they would say "I have `master` identifying commit `C`".  Our Git then enumerates the commits we've specifically asked to push, which is just commit `T`.  Our Git then knows that they have commit `C`, and therefore<sup>1</sup> they have commits `B` and `A` as well—the commit hash IDs are unique *everywhere*, not just in our own repository!  For us to *give* them commit `T`, then, we must give them everything needed to complete the graph that *leads to* `T`: we must give them `G`, because that's one of `T`'s parents, but we must also give them `E`, because that's another of `T`'s parents.  We must give them `F`, because `G` requires `F`.  We must give them `D`, because `E` requires `D`.  And then we will be done, because `F` and `D` require `C`, but they already have `C`.

Now that our Git has given their Git all the commits needed to complete the graph, our Git sends their Git a request of the form: *Please set your `featureA` to point to commit `T`.*  This `featureA` is the *second* part of the `featureA:featureA` pair in the `git push` command.  If you omit the `:featureA` second part, it's implied.

The first part, before the colon, determines which commit(s) our Git sends, so you can—sometimes—equally say `git push origin HEAD:featureA`, for instance.  However, the implied part is computed *using* the commit part, so if you were to instead run `git push origin master`, we would send them commit `E` and therefore also `D`, but *not* `F`, `G`, and `T`; and then we would request that they set their `master`.  Note that you can also push more than one thing at a time:

```
git push origin master featureA
```

will send all the commits—once only; there's no need to send `D` and `E` twice—then make *two* polite requests: *Please set your `master` to point to `E`, and please set your `featureA` to point to `T`.*

It's up to the other Git whether to *allow* these settings.  They will tell you if they accept or reject each of your requests.  If they agree to set their `featureA`, *your* Git will now, in your own repository, remember that *their* `featureA` points to commit `T`.  If you don't ask them to set their `master`, nothing will happen to your `origin/master` (your memory of their `master`).<sup>2</sup>

As a general rule, when your Git asks their Git to set one of their existing branch names, their Git checks whether doing so would *retain* all the commits that they already have, and merely *add new commits* to the end of the chain.  If so, that operation is a *fast-forward*, and is allowed.  If not, that operation is a *non-fast-forward* and by default, is rejected.  Consider, for instance, what would happen if they *did* have a name `featureA`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        F--I--J   <-- featureA
```

and we sent them our `D-E` and `F-G` and `T` and they took ours: their `I` and `J` would no longer be reachable; their repository would have:

```
            I--J   [no name]
           /
          F--G--T   <-- featureA
         /     /
        /_-D--E
       //
A--B--C    <-- master
```

Once there is no *name* for a commit, that commit can be<sup>3</sup> *garbage collected* and removed from the repository.  So this winds up throwing away commits `I` and `J`, which is why they will reject it by default.

---

<sup>1</sup>This inference, that having a commit implies having everything in history *before* that commit, is not actually usable in a *shallow clone*, in which some history is deliberately omitted.  However, the push action still works the same way.  Git actually uses an offer/request protocol in most cases, and in others, where the communication stream is limited, works within the constraints of the DAG.

<sup>2</sup>In principle, your Git could update its memory of all of their branches here, as long as they have listed all of them.  However, suppose they were to tell us that their `master` identified commit `H`.  If we do not have commit `H`, we would have to obtain commit `H` first, as Git chooses never to store names that point to commits that we do not have locally.  We use `git fetch` to get, from their Git, the list of all their branches and commits and then to obtain any of their commits that we do not have.  So `git push` only updates names when it gets "OK, I did your requested setting" responses, i.e., only updates the names that were successfully pushed.

<sup>3</sup>To avoid throwing commits away too quickly in *your own* repository, *your* Git has special hidden names, in what Git calls *reflogs*, that retain *all* your commits for at least 30 days by default.  Servers that accept `git push` commands, however, have reflogs disabled by default—so a force push that does lose commits can really *lose* commits, right away.  For various other once-good reasons, server Gits tend to run `git gc` right after finishing a push-receive as well.  (Git's new "quarantine" area for incoming commits eliminates the need for a post-receive GC, but there are lots of older servers out there.)